# Missing file from installed app with Windows Packaging Project

Tags: winforms, appsettings, appxmanifest

Ok. Not sure where to start from.

So, A .NET Core WinForms app was packaged with a Windows Package Project but after installation of the app, it throws an exception when trying to start app, as is shown below in the image.

[image: Missing file exception]

Such file (appsettings.json) should be in installation directory as it's supposed to be copied always into the output directory when building the app, and in fact, it's being copied but I think it's something related to the Windows Packaging Project.

Not sure how to solve this issue.

Best regards!